# Is there a point to having a function which only calls another function?

Tags: c++

Looking through the source code of a 90s Doom source port (Retrodoom in this case), I found this:

```
void A_Detonate(mobj_t *actor, player_t *player, pspdef_t *psp)
{
    P_RadiusAttack(actor, actor->target, actor->info->damage, false);
}
```

This A_Detonate function only serves as a caller to the P_RadiusAttack function, so the question is: why not just use P_RadiusAttack without a "parent" function?

Comment: For the better readability.

Comment: because it calls `P_RadiusAttack` in a very specific way that changes it to mean `A_Detonate`. It gives the code more context. It's absolutely necessary. Plus, imagine if the `false` parameter (or any other parameters) changed when a "detonate" happened. You'd have to change it everywhere you meant to do a "detonate". Would you remember where you meant "detonate" and not a different form of "RadiusAttack"?

Comment: "only calls another function?" -->well its does deference some members and passes in a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are sometimes used to increase the readability for developers, it may be doing something in a slightly slower way, but it makes the code a lot easier to maintain.

The function P_RadiusAttack may be used by multiple other functions, imagine a place in the code which calls 10 different "actions" aside from detonate, and they all call P_RadiusAttack in a different way. It would be a lot more readable and a lot easier to maintain to have functions of the names of the actions than to have 10 calls to P_RadiusAttack in slightly different ways.

Those functions may do more than calling P_RadiusAttack, or they may call it with different parameters, this way, the code would be quite unstructured if you only change A_Detonate.

Also, the function is actually already doing something, as you can see, the parameters for the 2 functions are different, in fact, putting the right parameters in the right place is already something which the function did.

Comment: You do raise a good point, but could you further elaborate on what you mean by your last paragraph of "putting the right parameters in the right place"? Would that mean that P_RadiusAttack could not be called without calling A_Detonate first?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of separating the interface from the implementation. So the users of

```
void A_Detonate(mobj_t *actor, player_t *player, pspdef_t *psp)
```

such as yourself can continue to use the same function signature in their code when maybe in the future the maintainers of `A_Detonate` might decide to do something like this

```
void A_Detonate(mobj_t *actor, player_t *player, pspdef_t *psp)
{
    P_DiameterAttack(actor, actor->target, actor->info->damage, false);    
    P_RadiusAttack(actor, actor->target, actor->info->damage, false);
    P_DumbAttack(actor, actor->target, actor->info->damage, false);
}
```

In other words the implementation of the function can change independently but the users of the function are blissfully unaware as they should be.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't implementing calls for P_DiameterAttack and P_DumbAttack inside the P_RadiusAttack function accomplish the same thing?

Also, would it even be a good thing if the users would be unaware of the changes to their code, they may not want to include calls for P_DiameterAttack and P_DumbAttack.

Comment: you might want to read up on APIs - Application Programming Interfaces and abstraction. Yes it is a good thing if the users of an API are unaware of how it is implemented. Whenever changes are made to the implementation of an API try and imagine what would happen if the API signature changed as well. The millions of users would have to update their code which is not a good thing and that is just one disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by arguments, it's a handler. A_Detonate isn't even using its player object and psp. Existence of such function suggests that somewhere is code that works with such signature, either for unification purposes, as adapter or as a handler.